# Facebook Graph v2: Request attenting friends from event

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

With Fb Graph v2 it isn't possible anymore to get a list of friends, {user-id}/friends only will only return any friends who have used (via Facebook Login) the app making the request. 
A found solution would be {user-id}/taggable_friends, but this will not return an uid, so it is not possible to compare this list with {event-id}/attendings.

So to me it seems that with die new Open/Closed Graph Api it's not possible anymore to provide this feature to users of my app.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After extensive research it turns out that there's no possibiltiy to get attending friends from events with Fb Graph v2. The feature request friends information on FB was removed on purpose in Fb-Graph v2.

Friends request will always only return any friends who have used (via Facebook Login) the app making the request.

[Graph API Reference /{user-id}/friends](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/friends)

For furhter information see [this so-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-use-m).